# Get image through instance method

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am trying to get image in return from the instance method, i am declaring the method in following way, but giving error. I am using NSObject class.

```
-(UIImage *)getAdImg;
```

This is giving error that "Expected a type". What does it mean. I normal view controller it is working fine, but in NSObject class it is giving this error. Please guide for the above.
Thanks in advance.

This is my .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSON.h"

@interface adClass : NSObject
{
NSString *mStrPid;
NSString *mStrAppUrl;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mStrPid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mStrAppUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mArrAdsDesc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mArrDeviceType;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mDevice;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mImgStr;

-(void)iphoneDevice;

-(UIImage *)getAdImg;   //(error line)

@end
```

Comment: Where did you get the error ? Please post the related code ? If the error is in .h file, please add your .h file code here

Comment: i think error is somewhere else

Comment: The line i posted ids giving error, no further coding done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` (where `UIImage` is declared)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
-(UIImage *)getAdImg
{
  UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]init];
  image.images=/**An Array of images**/
   return ima;
 }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Please look the post again.

Comment: @iPhone try +(UIImage *)getAdImg

Comment: When i type this method get error at same time "Expected a type".

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html read the docs first. UIImage is defined in /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework. Have you included this?